# Change parts of an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a urlString that is: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kdEhVtNFPo`

I want to be able to change it into this: `http://www.youtube.com/v/5kdEhVtNFPo`

How would I go about doing that? I'm not sure if I should use the instance methods `substringWithRange:` or `substringFromIndex:`

I tried this which removes the first part and just leaves the video id (it removes `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`) now I just need to add `http://www.youtube.com/v/` to the start of the string.

```
NSString *newUrlString = [urlString substringFromIndex:31];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString* newUrl = [oldUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"watch?v=" withString:@"v/"];
```

Please note that this only works as long as the URL won't contain more instances of the string "watch?v=".

Answer (score 2):

I'll propose a different way that may be more flexible on the inputs you give it:

```
- (NSString) newURLStringForOldURLString:(NSString *)oldURLString
{
    NSString *newURLString = nil;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:oldURLString];
    NSString *query = [url query]; /* v=5kdEhVtNFPo */
    NSArray *fieldValuePairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    for (NSString *pair in fieldValuePairs) {
        NSArray *components = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *field = [components objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *value = [components objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([field isEqualToString:@"v"]) {
            newURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@:%@/%@/%@", [url scheme], [url domain], [url port], field, value];
            break;
        }
    }
    [url release];
    return newURLString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative :

```
NSString *str3 = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kdEhVtNFPo";
NSString *outputString;
NSRange range = [str3 rangeOfString:@"watch?v="];
if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    outputString = [str3 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"v/"];
    NSLog(@"%@",outputString);

}
```

Comment: Personally I hate double Nots. Nothing wrong with your answer. I would rather place my code in else section.

Answer (score 0):

To be flexible enough, you could use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSString *str = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kdEhVtNFPo";
NSString *pattern = @"((?:http:\\/\\/){0,1}www\\.youtube\\.com\\/)watch\\?v=([:alnum:]+)";
NSString *template = @"$1v/$2";
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression 
          regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern 
                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                 error:nil];
NSString *newStr = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str 
          options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:template];
NSLog(@"Replaced: %@", newStr);
```